# django count a field but group by another

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

So I am using django with mysql, and I have a model `MyModel`, which contains some items with `None` on the `region` field. When I run this:

```
results = MyModel.objects.all()\
        .values('region')\
        .annotate(total=Count('region'))
```

it returns the grouping correctly, but one is `{'None': 0}`, which is incorrect, because there are some items with `region` field equal to `None`.

Now, if I were using `mysql` then I could group this with:

```
select region, count(id) from model_table group by region;
```

which returns the solution I want `| NULL   |         5 |`.

How can I achieve this from django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually already wrote the answer in your question. As far as I know, COUNT in SQL excludes certain falsey values like NULL. So if you want to count the falsey values as well, you use another field to perform the aggregate, just like you did in your SQL statement where you used the 'id' field. On that note, all you need to do is to perform COUNT on 'id'. Change your code to something like this:

```
results = MyModel.objects.all()\
    .values('region')\
    .annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

Comment: omg, you are totally right, I didn't think that was the way to go, but yeah it was that simple. thanks.